# HtmlInput Reset Problem

Tags: asp.net

my dropdown country is inside updatepanel and also set update mode conditional .Based on the country i am filling the state dropdown that also inside updatepanel and also set update mode conditional.

What i need is i want to reset the country and state dropdown.

I am using htmlinputbutton reset  which is not working for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a asp:button and then you need to register on your update panel the click event of the button. Then you can define code in your server side button click event to reload the dropdown. Don't forget that your whole page will regenerate though and that in your Page_Load you need to manage Page.IsPostback

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="ButtonReset_OnClick" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in `ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged` set the State drop down

in `ButtonReset_OnClick` reset both drop downs

You'll still need to register both events with the panel with the panel set to update=conditional

Comment: in button reset i have to manually assign the dropdown index to 0?

Comment: doing that sets the selected item in the drop down to the top item.  If that's your blank/select one value, then yes.